# Cyberpunk 2077 - Influence with Johnny Silverhand

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

So far, I've had trouble getting my influence with Johnny over 60%.  I'm curious to know how high others have made it.  Are there are any tried-and-true methods to raise your influence with him?

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that 70% is the highest that you can get your influence with Johnny.  Mostly, you can get 60% just by following simple guidelines ([laid out in IGN's walkthrough](https://www.ign.com/wikis/cyberpunk-2077/How_to_Get_Johnny%27s_Relationship_to_70%25)) of being nice to Johnny and not taking the Omega Blockers when there are other conversation options.

But it seems like there's one conversation in the side gig "Chippin' In" which can get you that extra 10%.  However doing that, requires you to select certain, [specific conversation options when you and Johnny are at the Oil Fields](https://www.ign.com/wikis/cyberpunk-2077/How_to_Correctly_Respond_to_Johnny_in_the_Oil_Fields).  These aren't terribly intuitive, because some of them require you to be confrontational to Johnny.  Basically,  select these conversation options, shown in order of when you are prompted:

- "Let's do something about that." Be sure to inscribe Johnny's initials when prompted.
- "The Guy who Saved My Life"
- "Nah, fucked the up too."
- "What do you want from me?"
- "OK. But as second chances go, this is your last."
- "You were a real dick in the beginning."
- "When you said you let down your friends..."
- "Yeah, I'll call Rogue."

Evidently, this is the only conversation with Johnny which matters in terms of unlocking the secret ending.